# Macro for defaulted constructors possible, pending compiler support?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, c++03

```
struct Foo {
    int data;
    Foo() = default;
    Foo(const Foo& arg) = default;
};
```

But my compiler [doesn't have defaulted constructors yet](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx).

Can I define a macro like `DEFAULTED` to stand in for `= default`? If it just left the line as

```
    Foo(const Foo& arg);
```

would the compiler still generate its default, or would it complain?

Comment: It seems difficult since the behavior of the "= default" stuff changes in function of the wanted function (default/copy constructor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can:

```
#if __cplusplus == 201103L
# define DEFAULTED(func) func = default;
#else
# define DEFAULTED(func)
#endif

struct foo
{
    DEFAULTED(foo())
};
```

However: Some compilers support parts of C++11, and may set `__cplusplus` to `201103L` even though they don't support default constructors.

Comment: But if you do that in C++03, won't the compiler ask for the function definition since you're redeclaring it?

Comment: @Morwenn Correct. Updated answer to either generate a defaulted constructor, or nothing at all (which will make "default" constructor" in old C++03).

Comment: I take it this code would have to be updated as soon as any version after 201103L was used, since the check is for ==. But by then it's probably worth just updating the code to =default.